# Replacement for "technically oriented"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have the following context:

> Since a young age, my parents encouraged me to be **technically oriented**. I studied subjects like math a programming *[...]*.

Is there a word that can replace "**technically oriented**"?

Comment: lacking context, but I would try to make the writing more concrete from the sample you provided. Paint a picture of the sort of things you did, and the sort of things you parents did. (Assuming something like an application). (i.e): My interest in technology started with my parents. Some of my best memories are building a circuit to make my toy train run, discovering the math behind everyday things such as". Usually people would rather read a "story" than general asseritions.

Comment: It's not quite what you want because it includes interests in low tech areas and more traditional craft skills but the nearest I can get is **practical**.

Answer (score 1):

Yoy may use ***geeky***.

> Since a young age, my parents encouraged me to be ***geeky***. I
>   studied subjects like math a programming [...].

**M-W**:

> **[geek](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/geek)**
>   *noun*
>
> **3** :  an enthusiast or expert especially in a technological field or
>   activity : *computer geek*
>
> - **geeky** *adjective*

Also perhaps ***nerdish/nerdy*** but this has a negative connotation.

**M-W:**

> **[nerd](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nerdy)**
>   *noun*
>
> :  an unstylish, unattractive, or socially inept person; especially : 
>   one slavishly devoted to intellectual or academic pursuits : *computer
>   nerds*
>
> - **nerdish**  *adjective*
> - **nerdy**  *adjective*

Comment: +1: LOL! As much as I can't disagree with the definitions, I don't think it's appropriate for the larger context.

Answer (score 1):

There's a recent word for this: STEM (Science, Technology, Engineering and Mathematics)

> From a young age, my parents encouraged me to get involved in STEM.

or you could say "get involved in STEM fields" or "take classes in STEM".  It's not charming, but it's more formal than *geek* and *geeky*.  (If informal is okay, then I fully support "geeky".)

Answer (score 0):

You can use fully equipped or totipotent.
You can also change the sentence like they have always encouraged me to study in technical subjects that can be handy in engineering or college.

Comment: This site strives to provide objective answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective and could be improved by adding [references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/59/77227). Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good answers.